# How to "correctly" check a property name against its' value?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following `User` class:

```
export class User {
    public id: number;

    //Some basic information
    public email: string;
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;

    //Permissions - what matters for my question
    public canHangSocks: boolean;
    public canDrinkEggnot: boolean;
    public canReachMistletoe: boolean;
    public canSleepWhileSantaInChimney: boolean;
}
```

I created a directive for setting an action button's `disabled` state according to each correspondent permission:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[checkPermission]'
})
export class ActionButtonCheckerDirective {
  private currentUser: User;
  @Input() checkPermission: string;

  constructor(
    private host: NbActionComponent,
    private rootStore: Store<ApplicationState>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rootStore.pipe(select(fromApp.getCurrentUser).subscribe((user: User) => {
      this.currentUser = user;
      this.host.disabled = this.validateUserPermission(this.checkPermission);
    });
  }

  validateUserPermission(permissionName: string): boolean {
    return !this.currentUser[permissionName];
  }
}
```

Implementation:

`<nb-action checkPermission="canHangSocks" nbTooltip="Hang Socks"></nb-action>`

My question is - how can I make a mix up of string enums and class properties, in order to:

1. Enforce `checkPermission` to be of a type (`Permission` instead of `string`, for example)
2. Make the code readable and nice?

A fantasy solution, written in English:

> `User` class extends `Permission`
> enum, which has all of the auth definitions. By extending that enum,
> `User` has each enum member added as a property.

Thanks!

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel, there is actually a library that does this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to split your User into generics and permissions like this then you can use the type "keyof" :

```
class UserPermissions {
  canHangSocks: boolean;
  canDrinkEggnot: boolean;
  canReachMistletoe: boolean;
  canSleepWhileSantaInChimney: boolean;
}

export class User extends UserPermissions {
  public id: number;
  public email: string;
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
}

const fn = (perm: keyof UserPermissions) => {};
```

I'd prefer to use a private array of permissions in my User and implement the check function directly in User :

```
enum Permissions {
  canHangSocks = 'canHangSocks',
  canDrinkEggnot = 'canDrinkEggnot',
  canReachMistletoe = 'canReachMistletoe',
  canSleepWhileSantaInChimney = 'canSleepWhileSantaInChimney',
}

class User {
  public id: number;
  public email: string;
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;

  private permissions: Permissions[] = [];

  public hasPermission(permission: Permissions) {
    return this.permissions.includes(permission);
  }
}

userInstance.hasPermission(Permissions.canHangSocks);
```

That way adding a permission seems easier to me and the enum can be used everywhere to check a permission.

Comment: Thanks. The first approach would not change the way the permission is being passed into the directive. The second approach would drag me into either changing the model or the server side or add a "middleware" converting server result (property-per-permission into array of permissions)

Comment: I don't do angular anymore so it is hypothetical to me but doing `@Input() checkPermission: keyof UserPermissions;` doesn't do the trick ? writting `<nb-action checkPermission="canInexistantPermission" />` should throw an error, shouldn't it ?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with object prototype of `hasOwnProperty`.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[checkPermission]'
})
export class ActionButtonCheckerDirective {
  private currentUser: User;
  @Input() checkPermission: string;

  constructor(private host: NbActionComponent, 
              private rootStore: Store<ApplicationState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rootStore.pipe(select(fromApp.getCurrentUser).subscribe((user: User) => {
      this.currentUser = user;
      this.host.disabled = !user.hasOwnProperty(this.checkPermission);
    });
  }

}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Thanks @noamyg and @bossno

Comment: How does your answer remotely relates to my question? Actually, it would make permission check to always be true.

Comment: Here you passed `checkPermission`  is static value?